# PHP Communication with Smtp

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a mail application that send about 5000 emails daily(a lot of account paperwork) via cron job, and **works fine when the mail is sending to just one recipient**. **The problem comes when we activate the BCC copy**, then the app starts sending until 980-1050 mails and start recieving `4.5.3` error from the smtp(Too many recipients). If i pause the job and run the cron again, the php process got a new pid, and start sending ok until it reach the same limit(980-1050 mails);

So my question is: **is there a way to regenerate the php process id ?**

If i was capable to do that, then the app would send those mails without problem.

**Or maybe i'm missing some postfix configuration?**

Relevant part of the code:

```
/**
* _Send_SmtpData
* Handles the SMTP negotiation for sending the email header and body.
*
* @param String $rcpt_to The 'receipt to' address to send the email to. This is a bare email address only.
* @param String $to The 'to' address to send this to. This can contain a name / email address in the standard format ("Name" <email@address>)
* @param String $subject The subject of the email to send.
* @param String $body The body of the email to send.
* @param String $headers The headers of the email to send.
**/ 

function _Send_SmtpData(&$rcpt_to, &$to, &$subject, &$body, &$headers)
{

    $data = "DATA";

    $this->DebugMemUsage('Trying to put ' . $data);

    if (!$this->_Put_Smtp_Connection($data)) {
        $this->ErrorCode = 12;
        $this->ErrorCodeSMTPEnhanced = false;
        $this->Error = GetLang('UnableToSendEmail_Data');
        $this->_Close_Smtp_Connection();

        $this->DebugMemUsage('Got error ' . $this->Error);

        return array(false, $this->Error);
    }

    $response = $this->_get_response();

    $this->DebugMemUsage('Got response ' . $response);

    $responsecode = substr($response, 0, 3);

    if ($responsecode != '354') {
        $this->ErrorCode = $responsecode;
        $this->ErrorCodeSMTPEnhanced = $this->_GetSMTPEnhancedErrorCode($response);
        $this->Error = $response;
        $this->_Close_Smtp_Connection();

        $this->DebugMemUsage('Got error ' . $this->Error);

        return array(false, $this->Error);
    }

    $msg = "To: " . $to . $this->_smtp_newline . "Subject: " . $subject . $this->_smtp_newline . $headers . $this->_smtp_newline . preg_replace('/^\.(\r|\n)/m', ' .${1}', $body);

    $msg = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$msg);
    $msg = str_replace("\r","\n",$msg);
    $lines = explode("\n",$msg);
    foreach ($lines as $no => $line) {
        // we need to rtrim here so we don't get rid of tabs before the start of the line.
        // the tab is extremely important for boundaries (eg sending multipart + attachment)
        // so it needs to stay.
        $data = rtrim($line);

        $this->DebugMemUsage('Trying to put ' . $data);

        if (!$this->_Put_Smtp_Connection($data)) {
            $this->ErrorCode = 13;
            $this->ErrorCodeSMTPEnhanced = false;
            $this->Error = GetLang('UnableToSendEmail_DataWriting');
            $this->_Close_Smtp_Connection();

            $this->DebugMemUsage('Got error ' . $this->Error);

            return array(false, $this->Error);
        }
    }

    $data = $this->_smtp_newline . ".";

    $this->DebugMemUsage('Trying to put ' . $data);

    if (!$this->_Put_Smtp_Connection($data)) {
        $this->ErrorCode = 14;
        $this->ErrorCodeSMTPEnhanced = false;
        $this->Error = GetLang('UnableToSendEmail_DataFinished');
        $this->_Close_Smtp_Connection();

        $this->DebugMemUsage('Got error ' . $this->Error);

        return array(false, $this->Error);
    }

    $response = $this->_get_response();

    $this->DebugMemUsage('Got response ' . $response);

    $responsecode = substr($response, 0, 3);
    if ($responsecode != '250') {
        $this->ErrorCodeSMTPEnhanced = $this->_GetSMTPEnhancedErrorCode($response);
        $this->ErrorCode = $responsecode;
        $this->Error = $response;
        $this->_Close_Smtp_Connection();

        $this->DebugMemUsage('Got error ' . $this->Error);

        return array(false, $this->Error);
    }

    $this->DebugMemUsage('Mail accepted ');

    /**
     * We got this far, this means we didn't encounter any errors.
     * Cleanup previous error codes and variables since they are no longer relevant
     * with the current process iteration.
     */
    $this->Error = '';
    $this->ErrorCode = false;
    $this->ErrorCodeSMTPEnhanced = false;

    $this->_smtp_email_count++;
    return array(true, false);
}
```

Comment: Maybe we could have some code, maybe a sending loop ?

Comment: I'm gonna udate the question...wait

Comment: Your problem has to do with application structure more than anything.

Comment: Detecting whether your script has "crashed" before finishing and launching it again looks more complicate than simply sending less copies on each run.

Comment: The script doesn't crash, it just can negociate with the stmp when haves BCC and after sending like 1000 emails

Comment: Yes, I know the script does not crash, that's why I wrote "crash" (with [quotes](http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/)). My point is that it's probably easier and faster for you to edit your current code rather than build a monitoring system.

Comment: I think i'm gonna edit the code...it seems that for every socket connection it puts a limit of 50 messages and then reset the smtp connection..maybe that value is too high, i'm gonna lower it to 30 and makes some test this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the "bug" was in another function, the bcc copy function; in every call for the working process, it was not cleaning the previous bcc copies of the mail, but sum them until they reach the limit.